# Let $a$ and $b$ be integers such that $ab = 0$. Then either $a = 0$ or $b = 0$ or both

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, self-learning

> Let $a$ and $b$ be integers such that $ab = 0$. Then either $a = 0$ or $b = 0$ or both.

So, I am doing exercise in a Terence Tao-Analysis 1 book and I came up with the above problem.
At this point of the book the integers are represented as $x\in Z, x = a-b; a,b \in N$. That is every integer has the form of subtraction of two numbers from $N$.

The idea that I tried to implement while solving the problem was to break down into the cases for positive and positive, negative and negative, and positive and negative integers show that their products can not be $0$, hence the only remaining option is $a = 0$ or $b = 0$ or both. However, I don't succeded in doing so because at this point in the book I don't yet know that the cancelation law for the integers exists. But I do know that the cancelation law for $N$ exists.
Therefore I decided to change the strategy.

take $a = x-y; x,y\in N$

take $b = c-d; c,d\in N$

$ab = (x-y)(c-d) = (xc+yd)-(yc+xd)$ by definition

if $ab = 0$ then $(xc+yd)-(yc+xd)=0=0-0$, so $xc+yd=yc+xd$-by definition

$xc-xd = yc-yd$

*then $x(c-d) = y(c-d)$

because for any $x \in N$ and $a-b \in Z$ $x(a-b) = (x-0)(a-b)=(xa+0b)-(0a-xb)=xa - (x(-b)) = xa-(x(b-0))=xa-xb$

since any natural number $n = n-0$

At this point my strategy is to use $x(c-d) = y(c-d)$ and induct on $c \in N$.

Base case: $c = 0$ $x(0-d) = y(0-d)$; $x(-d) = y(-d)$; $-xd=-yd$ at this point I will be good if I can proof that $(-1)a = -a$ for any $a \in Z$

Inductive step: Assume $x(c-d) = y(c-d)$ then $x((c++)-d) = y((c++)-d)$ then $xc+x-xd = yc+y-yd$, then $x+x(c-d)=y+y(c-d)$ by inductive hypothesis $x=y => a=0$.

Here also it seems to me like I am cheating. I think I can not make such an assumption from the inductive hypothesis since I am using cancelation law for integers which I don't know yet.

Please, can you clarify if the logic that I am using is plausible or not? If yes, can you help me to carry on?

Comment: The integers are equivalence classes of pairs $a-b$ with $a,b$ natural numbers. The equivalence given by $a_1-b_1=a_2-b_2$ if $a_1+b_2=a_2+b_1$. By induction, you can prove that there is always an element of each equivalence class in which one of the elements of the pair is zero. In your argument you are changing $c$, but $x,y,c,d$ are given. Well the equivalence classes of the pairs $(x,y)$ and $(c,d)$ are given. What you can do, is change the pair $c,d$ within the equivalence class. Change it to one in which either $c$ or $d$ is zero.

Comment: @conditionalMethod Please, can you elaborate a bit? I don't see how I can change $(c-d)$. The only thing that comes to my mind is $c-d=c+(-d)$ by definition. However, I don't see how it can help me.

Comment: @conditionalMethod  Do you mean view cases on (c,d)? a) if $c>d: c-d=n; n \in N$, $x(c-d)=y(c-d) =>xn=yn=>x=y=>a = 0$ by cancelation law for $N$. b) if  $c=d => b=0$ c) if $c<d, c-d=-n; x(-n)=y(-n)$ here I can not apply cancelation law for $N$ since $-1 \not \in N$. Therefore, I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: That's right. Given an integer $c-d$, if $c>0$ and $d>0$, then the pair is equivalent to $s^{-1}(c)-s^{-1}(d)$, where I am denoting by $s$ the successor function and by $s^{-1}$ the predecessor. Use whatever notation you have. By induction, if $k=\min(c,d)$, then the pair $c-d$ is equivalent to $s^{-k}(c)-s^{-k}(d)$. In this pair one of the two elements is $0$. Then you can separate in the cases that you did: $c>d$, $c=d$ and $c<d$.

Comment: Let me do the case $c<d$, which was giving you trouble. If $c<d$, then the pair $c-d$ is equivalent to a pair $0-n$. Then your equation $\mathbf{0=ab}$ becomes $0-0=(x-y)(0-n)=(x\cdot 0+y\cdot n)-(y\cdot 0+x\cdot n)=yn-xn$. So, the pair $xn-yn$ is equivalent to the pair $0-0$. This means that $xn+0=yn+0$, or $xn=yn$. Now you can apply cancellation to get that $x=y$, which gives you that the pair $x-y$ is equivalent to $0-0$. This is, $\mathbf{a=0}$.

Comment: Above I tried writing the symbols for integers, like $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ in bold font, to distinguish them from the symbols for natural numbers. It helps you remember what you can do and cannot. In your comment you were writing equations like $x(-n)=y(-n)$. This has a mix of natural numbers $x,y$ and integers $-n$. The latter you better write it like $0-n$, by definition.

Comment: @conditionalMethod Thank you! I would love to accept your answer if you want. Copy it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Complete it and write the full answer.